# Problem with using the .save() in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When i wanna save a user with this code:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../model/User");

//validate
const joi = require("@hapi/joi");

const schema = joi.object({
  name: joi.string().min(1).max(255).required(),
  email: joi.string().max(255).email().required(),
  password: joi.string().min(8).max(255).required(),
});

router.post("/register", async (request, respond) => {
  const { error } = schema.validate(request.body);
  if (error) return respond.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
  const user = new User({
    name: request.body.name,
    email: request.body.email,
    password: request.body.password,
  });
  try {
    const savedUser = await user.save();
    respond.send(savedUser);
  } catch (err) {
    respond.status(500).send(err);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

it doesnt get any error but it also does not respond anything and does not save anything

Comment: Have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46569248/mongoose-do-not-return-saved-document-in-callback

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any client connection in your code. Don't forget to connect to your mongoDB server and open your connection before processing any operation. Otherwise it won't have any effect.

```
var db = new Db('test', new Server('localhost', 27017));
// Establish connection to db
db.open((err, db) => {
   // Do what you want
});
```

See this example of saving a document in nodeJS: [Save to MongoDB](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#save)